# Calculating the duration of days between two formatted dates in Python results in "OverflowError: int too big to convert"

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, date, duration

I have a DataFrame of 320000 rows and 18 columns.
Two of the columns are the project start date and project end date.
I simply want to add a column with the duration of the project in days.

```
df['proj_duration'] = df['END_FORMATED'] - df['START_FORMATED']
```

The data is imported from a SQL Server.

The dates are formated (yyyy-mm-dd).

When I run the code above, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 234, in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.array_to_timedelta64
>
> TypeError: Expected unicode, got datetime.timedelta
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> df['proj_duration'] = df['END_FORMATED'] - df['START_FORMATED']
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py",
> line 64, in new_method
> return method(self, other)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops_*init*_.py",
> line 502, in wrapper
> return _construct_result(left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops_*init*_.py",
> line 475, in _construct_result
> out = left._constructor(result, index=index)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
> line 305, in **init**
> data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py",
> line 424, in sanitize_array
> subarr = _try_cast(data, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py",
> line 537, in _try_cast
> subarr = maybe_cast_to_datetime(arr, dtype)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
> line 1346, in maybe_cast_to_datetime
> value = maybe_infer_to_datetimelike(value)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
> line 1198, in maybe_infer_to_datetimelike
> value = try_timedelta(v)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
> line 1187, in try_timedelta
> return to_timedelta(v)._ndarray_values.reshape(shape)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\timedeltas.py",
> line 102, in to_timedelta
> return _convert_listlike(arg, unit=unit, errors=errors)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\timedeltas.py",
> line 140, in _convert_listlike
> value = sequence_to_td64ns(arg, unit=unit, errors=errors, copy=False)[0]
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\timedeltas.py",
> line 943, in sequence_to_td64ns
> data = objects_to_td64ns(data, unit=unit, errors=errors)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\77797\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\timedeltas.py",
> line 1052, in objects_to_td64ns
> result = array_to_timedelta64(values, unit=unit, errors=errors)
>
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 239, in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.array_to_timedelta64
>
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 198, in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.convert_to_timedelta64
>
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 143, in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.delta_to_nanoseconds
>
> OverflowError: int too big to convert

I suspect that there is a problem in the formatting of the dates. I tried:

```
a = df.head(50000)['END_FORMATED']
b = df.head(50000)['START_FORMATED']
c = a-b
```

and got the same error. However, when I ran it for the last 50000 rows, it worked perfectly:

```
x = df.tail(50000)['END_FORMATED']
y = df.tail(50000)['START_FORMATED']
z = x-y
```

This shows that the problem does not exist in all of the dataset and only in some of the rows.

Any idea how I can solve the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a date in your SQL dataset set as 1009-01-06. pandas **only** understand dates between 1677-09-21 and 2262-04-11, as per [this oficial documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits).

Try to cast each Series into a datetime object to catch if some entry is not in the expected format, with `infer_datetime_format = True` and `errors = 'coerce'` as follows:

```
df['START_FORMATED'] = ['2020-05-05', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-07', 1009-01-06]
df['END_FORMATED'] = ['2020-06-05', '2020-06-06', '2020-06-07', '2020-06-08']

df['proj_duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_FORMATED'], infer_datetime_format = True, errors = 'coerce') - pd.to_datetime(df['START_FORMATED'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors = 'coerce')
```

This will set NaT value when impossible to use `pd.to_datetime()`, which resulted in this df:

```
      START_FORMATED END_FORMATED proj_duration
0         2020-05-05   2020-06-05       31 days
1         2020-05-06   2020-06-06       31 days
2         2020-05-07   2020-06-07       31 days
3         1009-01-06   2020-06-08           NaT
```

Comment: @ Jose Vega: Thanks. I ran it and I got this error:
"OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1009-01-06 00:00:00"

Comment: @SalmanTabatabai updated answer to match your question. Should work now, but be aware of NaT values that might arise from that.

Comment: Exactly! I realized that someone has put a sales end date in 3020!!!! Thanks for the follow-up.